# import an android project from android studio to Titanium studio

Tags: android, titanium-alloy, titanium-android

How to import an android project from android studio to 
Titanium studio?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Android Studio is fully compatible with Titanium. Because Titanium does not support all native android features.

In either case check out this [Link](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Importing+an+Existing+Project).

Comment: OK Thank you Snow. Is there anyway to import an android project created in eclipse to titanium studio??

Comment: i want to add a grid view that have created in android, i have to use it with titanium. is it possible?? answer me please.....

Comment: Are you talking about the Grid Layout? If yes, then layouts are not part of the Android Studio, you can use layouts in any IDE.

Comment: Cheers! You need to click the tick to accept answer.